# How to call Rest API in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, api

I am trying to call a Rest API call in sql. When I run this, I get a NULL in the ResponseText.

Note: The api-key, x-domain and host are not real in this example.  Could it be the setRequestHeader are not set correctly?

```
DECLARE @Object AS INT;

DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(400);

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', 'https://api3.website.com/v3/contacts', 'false'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'X-Auth-Token','api-key as152das24wdw52dstw53fsg'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'X-DOMAIN', 'em.website.com'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Host', 'api3.website.com'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'

Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

SELECT @ResponseText

Exec sp_OADestroy @Object
```

Comment: You need to check for errors after every call to sp_OAMethod.  See eg https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/de127f6c-4e7e-482c-8b33-996a60b038ff/sql-procedure-working-when-run-manually-not-running-from-sql-server-agent?forum=transactsql Stepping back can you use CLR instead?  It's easier and than COM automation.